# error when installing pyusb

Tags: python, package, pyusb

I have downloaded pysb 1.0 alpha and when in try to install it with this command ( python setup.py install) get this error:

```
error package directory 'usb' does not exist .
```

What can i do ?

Thanks .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to have python installed (v2.5 or higher). If already done, you can copy the usb folder from pyusb to the folder ..../python2x/lib/

I think that should work. Assuming you're using windows.